# I have problems with bluetooth mouse and bluetooth headphones simultanously in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, mouse, headphones, bluez

When starting up Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop (a Dell XPS-9343), my mouse (a Logitech MX Anywhere 2) connecting successfully - only a few warnings are in the log ( bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22) ).

The trouble starts when I'm also connecting to my headphones (Sony WH-1000XM3). I have to connect/disconnect my mouse and my headphones several times until it finally works.

The install of Ubuntu is a clean install - after I thought is was a problem with the upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04.

Has somebody a clue about this or is this also happend to someone else?

Comment: I just want to say, that I had problems connecting my headphones (Sony WH-1000XM2) with the default Ubuntu installation. I had to click *connect* several times until Ubuntu finally connected with them. Try connecting with the devices with`bluetoothctl` in the terminal. It works much better than via the gnome settings.

Comment: Thank you - will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that the firmware for bluetooth of my notebook is sometimes in a invalid state (it does not respond to any command given like connecting or pairing). After turning my laptop completely off and on again it magically works.

Answer (score 0):

Leave mouse paired. Unpair the headphones and pair them again.